# Form is not submitting to Google sheets

Tags: forms, astrojs

I am trying to modify an Astro website template, and I am trying to implement a simple email submission form through google forms + sheets on my page as an astro component in the sidebar. Except the form is not submitting the user entries to the google form as directed.

The weird thing is, I got this to work on my Contact form page, with the same code, just pulled from a markdown file. But I am not able to get this to work from the sidebar. The script seems to work, as it redirects to the submission confirmation page, but the entry data is not being sent over to google.

Here is what I have in email.astro

```html
<script is:inline type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>
<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" 
onload="if(submitted) {window.location='/posts/form-confirmation';}"></iframe>

<div class="rounded-lg bg-[var(--card-bg)]">
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/really-long-url/viewform" method="post" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
      <center><label class="italic font-bold ">Subscribe to get e-mails when I post: </label></center>
      <center><input type="email" placeholder=" example@somewhere.com" name="entry.number" class="mt-3 px-2 w-full " required /></center>
      <center><button type="submit" class="font-bold ">Subscribe</button></center>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is what I have in sidebar.astro

```js
import Email from "./email.astro";

const className = Astro.props.class;
// ...
// return
<div id="sidebar" class:list={[className, "w-full"]} transition:persist>
    <div class="flex flex-col w-full gap-4 top-4 sticky top-4" transition:animate="none">

        <Email></Email>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried moving the script for both forms into the main site layout, but that didn't change anything. Unsure what the problem is with this particular email form, especially since the exact same code is used for the Contact form that works.

Admittedly, I am in way over my head using this template so I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it wasn't an issue with the code at all, just the link. I took off the submit redirect to let it go to the default google forms confirmation page and got a 405 Method error. That clued me in that the URL itself was wrong. I replaced the url to have "formResponse" instead of the "viewForm" that was there originally, and it worked.

Noob mistake smh...